# Estimate for the solution of the wave equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, estimation, wave-equation

Let $y$ be the solution of the following nonlinear wave equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{ll}
y_{tt}-\Delta y + f(y) = F & (t,x)\in (0,T)\times(0,1)\\
y(.,0)=y(.,1)=0 & t\in(0,T)\\
y(0,.)=y^0 \in H^1_0(0,1), \,\, y_t(0,.)=y^1\in L^2(0,1) & x\in (0,1).
\end{array}
\end{cases}
$$
Where $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ the nonlinearity, and $F \in L^{2}((0,T)\times(0,1))$.

I want to obtain an estimate of the following term $||y(T,.)||_{H^1_0(0,1)}$ and $||y_t(T,.)||_{L^2(0,1)}$, in terms of $||y(0,.)||_{H^1_0(0,1)}$ and $||y_t(0,.)||_{L^2(0,1)}$ and probably $||y_{tt}-\Delta y + Ay||_{L^2((0,T)\times(0,1))}$.

My idea is that we can obtain such estimation (but only for the linear case):
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{ll}
y_{tt}-\Delta y + Ay = F & (t,x)\in (0,T)\times(0,1)\\
y(.,0)=y(.,1)=0 & t\in(0,T)\\
y(0,.)=y^0 \in H^1_0(0,1), \,\, y_t(0,.)=y^1\in L^2(0,1) & x\in (0,1).
\end{array}
\end{cases}
$$
Where $A\in L^{\infty}((0,T)\times (0,1))$ and $F \in L^{2}((0,T)\times(0,1))$.

is the estimation of the enegry defined as follows:
$$E(t)= ||y(t)||^2_{H^1_0(0,1)}+||y_t(t)||^2_{L^2(0,1)}$$
and we have the following
$$E(T)\leq C.E(0)e^{C\sqrt{||A||_{\infty}}}$$
for some $C>0$.

I'm stuck on the nonlinearity.

Comment: Please correct your title ("equation") and tell us what you try.

Comment: How regular is the solution $y$ assumed? When trying to obtain estimates for the solution of some PDE it is often helpful to multiply the equation with the solution itself and then use some kind of integration by parts in space and or time. Did you try such an approach?

Comment: @neca yes and it works for the second equation obviously because it's linear but the first one I tried and it doesn't give big results you still have to estimate the following integral : $\int_{(0,T)\times (0,1)}f(y) y dxdt$

Comment: Something like $\left| \int f(y)y dxdt \right| \leq \int |f(y) - f(0)||y| +|f(0)||y| dxdt \leq \int L_f |y|^2 + |f(0)||y| dxdt$ with $L_f$ being the Lipschitz constant of $f$? Then you could maybe proceed using Young's inequality / Gronwalls lemma to get rid of $y$ on the right side